# What is the difference between remote, local and alias queues

Tags: ibm-mq

Can somebody help to understand the basic of these 3 queues with example.when do we use all 3

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps a more simple explanation: Think of a local queue as a queue which exists on the queue manager it is defined.. you can PUT and GET messages off a local queue.  A remote queue is like a pointer to a queue on another queue manager which is usually on different host.  Therefore messages can be PUT to it (and they will usually arrive on a local queue at that remote host) but you cannot GET messages from a remote queue.

Answer (score 5):

A queue is known to a program as local if it is owned by the queue manager to which the program is connected; the queue is known as remote if it is owned by a different queue manager. The important difference between these two types of queue is that you can get messages only from local queues. (You can put messages on both types of queue.)

References:

1. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.csqzal.doc/fg10950_.htm
2. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.explorer.doc/e_queues.htm

Comment: Is it possible to have have two MQ's with same name (Q1) in two different queue managers (QM1, QM2) & then have QM1 storing remote defintion of Q1 as well as local of Q1?

Answer (score 4):

Simply put, a queue manager only ever hosts messages on local or transmition queues on that queue manager. If you want to go to another queue manager, you can use definitions which tell the queue manager that the 'put' is running on, how to route the message to a destination queue manager - however this ends up with a message on a transmit queue which is then picked up and sent down a channel towards that destination. Alias queues are just an opportunity to use a different name for another queue. Remote queues are definitions on one queuemanager with information about where the message should be routed.

MQ documentation:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.explorer.doc/e_queues.htm

Another description:
https://www.scribd.com/doc/44887119/Different-Types-Queues-in-Websphere-MQ

Answer (score 0):

An application which is connected to a local QueueManager which host a queue, So that queue will be local queue for that application. An application which is connected to a QueueManager which is located remotely and that host a queue that queue will be remote queue. we should always keeps in mind that we always read the message from the local queue. A message put on the remote queue, will be routed to local queue through the object defined on the local queue thrugh the channel and the transmission queue.